# Fingerprint log on, domain wide

Tags: active-directory, domain

All the users in my company use laptops with fingerprint readers built in. I use this on my laptop but the fingerprint is only stored locally. Is there a way to make it domain wide using the AD without going to each laptop and registering my fingerprint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose this would depend on the hardware vendor... does the fingerprint reader support using an identity store or database besides the local computer?

Comment: I actually don't know. My computer has Windows 8.1 and it automatically picked up the drivers and I just registered my finger through the windows sign in options. The laptop is a ThinkPad SL410. I'll see if I can find anything on the reader's database

Comment: If it only supports a local source of authentication, then you might be able to get everyone to register on one computer, and then distribute that database through Group Policy so that it's local on every computer. Just thinking out loud, here.

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprints (and other biometrics) on Windows are designed to replace the PIN on the machine and are keyed to the machine's TPM individually. The point is that if your fingerprint is stolen, it could not be used to access resources using a different machine.

There might be some third party tools that would allow you to do what you want, but that's not by design with Windows/Active Directory.